# How to make the counter start at a given number in tasks environment?

Tags: lists

Is there any other method other than this ?

I want it to be automatic just `\task` will do the job for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}
\task [15] 
\task [16]
\task [17] and so on 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}
\task [15] 
\task [16]
\task [17] and so on 
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `tasks` automatically counting? Do you want to continue counting between different `tasks` environments?

Comment: no to start counting at any given number like say, 27